# Default value is null always,Schema.DescribeFieldResult

Tags: apex, describesobject

I am trying to describe a field and get the default value but the following always outputs `null`.

```
Schema.DescribeFieldResult dfr = Account.SLASerialNumber__c.getDescribe();
system.debug('res '+dfr.getdefaultvalue()); // null
```

What I am missing ?

Comment: SLASerialNumber__c is picklist field ? Have you selected default value for this picklist ?

Comment: Its a Text field, yes default value is provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SLASerialNumber__c` is the `text field` so use below code

```
Schema.DescribeFieldResult F = Account.SLASerialNumber__c.getDescribe();
system.debug(F.getDefaultValueFormula());
```

run this code in dev console

---

For picklist

```
Schema.DescribeFieldResult F = Account.Active__c.getDescribe();
List <Schema.PicklistEntry> pickVals = F.getPicklistValues();        
for (Schema.PicklistEntry pv: pickVals) {
    if (pv.isDefaultValue()) {
        defaultVal = pv.getValue();
    }    
}
system.debug('Default value is' + defaultVal);
```

Comment: Thanks Man !! It worked ..
But the problem is in checkbox, it is always returning null.

Comment: Currently this is a known issue check this link https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008XL8AAM vote this issue to resolve